Can a Flutter project environment be set up in a completely isolated manner on macOS?
I am used to developing in Qt, where I can reasonably copy the entirety of a Qt project's code as well as the Qt SDK into a local directory, and use only those files when creating the build. This sandboxes every project's needs such that I never worry about new Qt projects affecting my core system. It also means that I have very good control over what versions of dependencies are used when compiling. (This is analogous, I suppose, to how pyenv works.)
Flutter, on the other hand, seems early-on to require system-changing actions. The installation directions require adding Flutter to the $PATH. (Ick.) And then Cocoapods installation on my computer runs into issues with Ruby versioning. Having lived through the apk dependency hell wars, I'm not particularly keen to start randomly upgrading things on my core system. I would hate to break something important just so I can futz around with a few contributions to a FOSS project.
In a world where hard disk space is cheap, and time recovering from failed installs is extremely expensive, on macOS can a Flutter project be set up to be 100%[*] isolated to a local directory, including all Cocoapods, ruby, etc... dependencies?
[*] As discussed in the comments, XCode is both necessary for Flutter and unavoidably a system-wide installation. However, t is also an Apple product and so is, in a sense, an Apple extension of macOS. So let's say "isolating everything required except for Apple system products"

The compiled output binary is self-contained.  But the dev environment does entail quite a few subsystems, like the flutter sdk, xcode, and cocoapods.

@RandalSchwartz thanks for the comment. I clarified my question to state that I'm asking specifically about the dev environment.

You can use homebrew to isolate most of the third party stuff, but XCode wants to be installed as a system tool and the paths are baked in.

@RandalSchwartz That's a fair point about XCode. It is, however, an Apple tier one product, and in a certain light could be considered to be a part of macOS-dev, so it's got a certain degree of reliability and ongoing support above the rest.

I'll look into homebrew, thanks!
